# Assigning the result of a stored procedure, within a stored procedure, to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My script is returning two values where only one is required. I want to assign the result of executing Sel_NPCA_Min_PlanID_ByID to the last part of the coalesce argument. Is this do-able?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sel_NPCA_PlanID]
(@ID int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @PlanID int
EXEC @PlanID = Sel_NPCA_Min_PlanID_ByID @ID

SELECT
COALESCE(checkboxTicked.PLAN_ID, firstPlanDiscussedAgreed.PLAN_ID,     firstPlanAgreed.PLAN_ID, @PlanID) AS PLAN_ID
        FROM referral   
            LEFT JOIN checkboxTicked
                ON referral.ID = checkboxTicked.ID          
            LEFT JOIN firstPlanDiscussedAgreed
                ON referral.ID = firstPlanDiscussedAgreed.ID AND checkboxTicked.PLAN_ID IS NULL         
            LEFT JOIN firstPlanAgreed
                ON referral.ID = firstPlanAgreed.ID AND checkboxTicked.PLAN_ID IS NULL AND firstPlanDiscussedAgreed.PLAN_ID IS NULL     
WHERE referral.ID = @ID

END
```

Comment: First, how would changing the value in the column affect the fact that two values are being returned?  Second, your `coalesce()` seems like it would be doing what you want.  To clarify the question, you should show what the stored procedure is returning, what you want it to return, and perhaps sample data from the tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's the top level stored procedure, Sel_NPCA_PlanID, that is returning two values when only one is required. Ultimately just one int is required. Sorry if I've misunderstood your question but does that answer it?

Comment: Add `top 1` if you only want one value.  That has nothing to do with the `coalesce()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sel_NPCA_PlanID returns one int and Sel_NPCA_Min_PlanID_ByID another int when for instance I execute 'EXEC Sel_NPCA_PlanID 1233'. The coalesce obviously has a pecking order and I'm not sure picking the top 1 out of the two returned results would be correct?

Comment: What about using OUTPUT parameter in your Sel_NPCA_Min_PlanID_ByID  Stored Procedure?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before but I just created a scalar function to get the last value for coalesce. Thank you for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the output of a procedure to a variable, you should probably have a (scalar) function instead of a procedure. Other option is to use output variables in the procedures parameter list.